# Email Validation in J2EE

Tags: java, validation, email

I think many answers had been given to this question that i am going to ask but still i didn't get the exact answer for this.

My question is simple that how can i apply particular email validation of my domain. For example: in my text box whenever a user writes an email on it, the emails having expression like sample@suraj.com should only enter in my database. No gmail.com, yahoo.com, etc should enter in it.

for other things like @ and . i used input type="email". But what can i do for the upper problem. Thank you

Comment: Thanks for marking it duplicate. Can u please specify the code here from the already mentioned answers

Comment: I would use client side validation in your case.

Comment: @Ankit that's what i am looking for. Can you please specify a client side validation for my context. please

Comment: Refer to email validation section on this page https://www.javatpoint.com/javascript-form-validation

Comment: it's not the answer for my problem. Anyways i got my answer. Thanks